# Not able to see the webpage of the github repository

Tags: github

I am very new to github.
I pushed my repository into github.
And in settings page, they tell my site is published at 
`http://jerinzam.github.io/coi-site.` 
But that URL gives me a 404 page.

Can someone give some xplanation on this.

And also **FYI** my project uses MEAN stack

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://github.com/jerinzam/coi-site

Comment: @JuanC.:sorry dint get you????

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. GitHub won't run your site. It is only for static hosting, not Node.js hosting. It also doesn't support any databases, including MongoDB.
2. From [the project pages documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#project-pages):

   > - The `gh-pages` branch is used to build and publish Project Pages sites.

   You have three branches, but none of them are called `gh-pages`:

   - `gh-pa`
   - `gn-pages`
   - `master`

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly as above.
You can host your code repo on github, but the web link to that repo will literally be whatever it is in the browser.

Now if you are wanting to run your site, then try this - https://masteringmean.com/lessons/557-Setup-and-Getting-Started-Running-Your-Site

You will need to have the mongo server running before starting the server. Check this is running by typing $mongod
so just go to the directory then type $ node run.js